# Multiple models into one route and filtering for Ember select

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two models loading into one route (edit page) through the setupController function. This is because the page is using a dynamic segment. Within the edit page, I also have a select dropdown list which is populated via another api ("options" API).

I'm having trouble using the filter to filter through the api and then applying it to the ember select element. When I try and filter, I get an error. I can't seem to filter through the options API.

Here is a jsbin to demonstrate my problem: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/salivo/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing the async lookup and setting the two lists through the setupController entirely, instead of via computed controller functions, works just fine

http://jsbin.com/pahezivuli/2/edit?html,js,output